# Middleware responsibilities and usage: checking preconditions for business logic

Tags: api, middleware

I am developing an API backend in NestJS, now for some specific routes (or controllers) I am loading in a configuration from the database to handle an incoming request. This fetching of the configuration is done inside my service (business logic), but I was wondering that perhaps this can be separated using middleware. Idea is that I load in the configuration in the middleware and then pass it on to the service. To go even further I was thinking of checking preconditions with the incoming request and the configuration, in order to determine if the request should be passed on to the service.

I mostly see middleware being used for authentication and object validation preconditions, so I was not sure if the above would also be a right fit.

To give some further context, the configuration is request/user dependent and is not global.

So in short: Is this a proper usage of middleware? Or should the above be part of the business logic? If it should be part of the business logic, what would be a good way to separate the checking of preconditions with the actual logic itself?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you are right. The middleware should handle business logic alone.

It seems to me that the validation mechanism you have is considerably heavy. Hence, it is not uncommon to have a separate validation layer (a component or a service) between the user request and middleware. Separation of concerns is better implemented in this way and the api stack is loosely coupled.